# Angular 6/RxJS How to update table retrieving data through HTTP?

Tags: angular, typescript

I´m creating a [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyNoj.png) following the angular material [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdpkyybkkdo?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-http-example.ts) but, when I updated the information, the data isn´t refreshing in the table. I made a test and everything is working with the HTTP request. 
 I have the code in two parts:

### 1. ranges.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
            startWith({}),
            switchMap(() => {
                this.isLoadingResults = true;
                return this._ecommerceOrdersService.getData(this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
            }),
            map(data => {
                // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
                this.isRateLimitReached = false;
                this.resultsLength = data.meta.total;
                return data.data;
            }),
            catchError(() => {
                this.isLoadingResults = false;
                // Catch if the API has reached its rate limit. Return empty data.
                this.isRateLimitReached = true;
                return observableOf([]);
            })
        ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource = data);
}
```

### 2. _ecommerceOrdersService:

```
getData(sort: string, order: string, page: number): Promise<any> {
    const href = this.urlMtk + 'system/ranges';
    const requestUrl = `${href}?page=${page + 1}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let resp: any;
        this._httpClient.get(requestUrl)
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
                 this.ranges = response.data;
                 this.dataLength = response.meta.total;
                 this.onOrderChanged.next(this.ranges);
                 this.noData = false;
                 resolve(response);
            }, reject => {
                this.noData = true;
                resolve(reject);
                resp = reject;
                const dataerr = resp;
                this._Auth.showSnackBarUpss(dataerr, 'top');
                this._Auth.deniedPermission(resp.statusText);
            });
    });
}
```

I trying to call **getData** function inside the [refresh button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ge07.png) but it´s not working. 
This´s my first question here and I hope my description is clear. 
 Thank you so much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another `Subject` inside your merge. Let's call it `refresh`. If you add this to your `ranges.component.ts` and add this subject to the `merge` statement:

<sub>truncating code for readability purposes</sub>

```
readonly refresh = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  merge(
    this.sort.sortChange,
    this.paginator.page,
    this.refresh
  )
  // ...
}
```

Then you just need a way for your component to call this refresh. You can either do this straight from the template or have a function. I'll show you the straight from the template method. It's shorter and more readable, but a bit frowned upon:

```
<button mat-mini-fab (click)="refresh.next()">
  <mat-icon>plus</mat-icon>
</button>
```

You will now see the network request being done again.

<sub>On a side note, mixing `Promise` with `Observable` in your `getData` method is very anti pattern and reduces readability a lot. Try to stick with Observables, and use the `async` pipe in templates to consume the data. You can also use one Observable to create multiple ones, all containing a certain part of the data and repeat the data on subscription.</sub>

Comment: It works! thank you. I´m still new with reactive programming and of course, I really appreciate your note.